# Jquery Dialog empty loading partial view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm calling a Partialview in Jquery dialog
the dialog pops up and i can see the data for a second then i see only the title bar and the dialog is empty.
[image]

```
 $("#lnkCreate").on("click", function (e) {
        //e.preventDefault(); //use this or return false
        url = $(this).attr('href');

        $("#dialog-edit").dialog('open');

        return false;
    });

 $("#dialog-edit").dialog({
        title: 'Create User',
        autoOpen: false,
        resizable: true,
        width: 600,
        height:800,

        modal: true,
        draggable: true,
        open: function (event, ui) {
            $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide(); // Hide Close button
            //$(this).load(url);
            $(this).load("@Url.Action("CreatePartial", "Home", new { id = Model.User.Id })");

        },
        close: function (event, ui) { 
            location.reload(true);
        }
    });
```

and here how i call it

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Create New ", "CreatePartial","Home",new { id = Model.User.Id },new{id = "lnkCreate"})
```

I also have this warning on the browser

> Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

Comment: The warning is from using `async:false` in ajax request. I'm guessing you may have that set in a global method like `$.ajaxSetup`. Show us what the generated javascript in browser looks like. Is the `load()` url correct? If so what do you see in browser if you open that url?

Answer (score 0):

Some how i have to remove all javascript tags from my Partial view, however i have to figurout how to use validation and other js function without adding any script tag!!!